# htaccess redirect some partical url 301 SEO

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

something on our BLOG URLS have changed. 
No i want to have some URL path deleted in urls.

Example:

OLD URL: 
https://do-main.de/blog/**entry**/die-xxx-der-portrait

NEW URL: 
https://do-main.de/blog/die-xxx-der-portrait

My htaccess attempt to setup:

```
#OLD BLOG URLS
RewriteEngine On

# anything that is equal to https://do-main.de/blog/entry/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^do\-main\.de\/blog\/entry\/$

# redirects to https://do-main.de/blog/*
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://do-main.de/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

conclusion all URLS with "entry" should be only using /blog/ without /entry/
Do you understand? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `Redirect` directive.

```
Redirect 301 /blog/entry/ http://example.com/blog/
```

This will 301 redirect all requests from `example.com/blog/entry/foobar` to `http:// example.com/blog/foobar` .